# SortedList with value and simplified loops with lambda

Tags: c#, list, lambda, sortedlist

I have a block of codes here:

```
SortedList<char, int> alpha = new SortedList<char, int>();
List<string> A = new List<string>();
alpha.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);
foreach (var a in alpha)
    A.Add(a.Key + ":" + a.Value);
```

1. `alpha.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);` doesn't sort by value, but sorts by key. May I know what's the problem with the code?
2. can I simplify:

   `foreach (var a in alpha)
      A.Add(a.Key + ":" + a.Value);`

into one lambda statement? something like

```
alpha.ForEach(x => A.Add(a.Key + ":" + a.Value));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
SortedList<char, int> alpha = new SortedList<char, int>();
alpha.Add('B',1);
alpha.Add('A',2);
alpha.Add('C',3);
var A= alpha.OrderByDescending(a =>a.Value)
        .Select (a =>a.Key+":"+a.Value)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

The statement `alpha.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value);` has no effect... Linq operators are lazy, they're not executed until you enumerate their result. Since you're not using the result of `OrderByDescending`, it just creates a lazy sequence that *would* yield the items of `alpha` sorted by value, *if* you enumerated it... `OrderByDescending` doesn't sort the collection, it just returns a sorted sequence of items from the collection, without modifying the collection itself.

You should do it like this:

```
foreach (var a in alpha.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value))
    A.Add(a.Key + ":" + a.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, but <br> var A= alpha.OrderByDescending(a =>a.Value)
        .Select (a =>a.Key+":"+a.Value)
        .ToList();<br> works well for me